# pcap post request body string classification

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification

I want to classify malware traffic. I am going to use the machine learning method to classify the post request body string in the pcap file. The conventional text classification algorithm may not work because the string in the post request body may be irregular characters.

Comment: What is the question?